# Failing to add jQuery focus in a loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on a custom live validation for a form element - `textarea`. I am trying to add a `focus` listener in a for loop for every field from my array.

Code:

```
var fieldIds = ["field10","field8","field6","field5","field4"];
//On focus out/focus in
    for (var i=0; i<fieldIds.length;i++){
            $( "#"+fieldIds[i] ).focusout(function() {
                focusOutValidation(fieldIds[i]);
            });
            $( "#"+fieldIds[i] ).focus(function() {
                focusInValidation(fieldIds[i]);
            });
        }

    function focusOutValidation(fieldId){
        if ($('#'+fieldId).val().length == 0){
                $('#'+fieldId).removeClass('LV_valid_field');
                $('#'+fieldId).addClass('LV_invalid_field');
            }else{
                $('#'+fieldId).addClass('LV_valid_field');
                $('#'+fieldId).removeClass('LV_invalid_field');
            }
        }

    function focusInValidation(fieldId){
        if ($('#'+fieldId).val().length == 0){
            $('#'+fieldId).removeClass('LV_invalid_field');
        }
```

For some reason, during debugging, when I focus any of the fields from the array, the script goes to the `focusInValidation` function, but `fieldId` is undefined. Any idea?

Comment: Is there really no way you can use a common class for this?

Comment: BTW, jQuery does the loop for you: `var myFields = jQuery( '#field10,#field8,#field6,#field5,#field4' ); myFields.focus( /* … */ ); myFields.focusout( /* … */ );`

Comment: The reason your code doesn't work is in the answer of the above so-dupe question. To improve code use `var fieldIds = ["field10", "field8", "field6", "field5", "field4"];

var selector = '#' + fieldIds.join(', #');

$(selector).on('focus blur', function () {
    if($(this).val().length === 0) {
        $(this).addClass('LV_invalid_field').removeClass('LV_valid_field');
    } else {
        $(this).removeClass('LV_invalid_field').addClass('LV_valid_field');
    }
});`

Comment: Thank you, it works and it is much more efficient and clean.

Comment: I don't think the linked answer is really the best way to solve this. There is no need for anonymous functions here.